# Im trying to use this method to detect moving object. Can someone advise me for this?

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to ask about what kind of problems there be if i use this method to extract foreground.

The condition before using this method is that it runs on fixed camera so there're not going to be any movement on camera position.

And what im trying to do is below.

1. read one frame from camera and set this frame as background image. This is done periodically.
2. periodically subtract frames that are read afterward to background image above. Then there will be only moving things colored differently from other area
   that are same to background image.
3. then isolate moving object by using grayscale, binarization, thresholding.
4. iterate above 4 processes.

If i do this, would probability of successfully detect moving object be high? If not... could you tell me why?

Comment: I think It can be done if only camera is fixed. Otherwise not only your moving objects but every pixel in your frame will be change so you will be unable to detect moving objects.

Comment: The appropriate tag for the question is image/video processing, not C++ or openCV, as your question focuses on algorithm rather than implementation.

Comment: @Ophir Gvirtzer sorry i didn't know that tag exists. Thanks.

Comment: BTW I see that 3 people have taken the time to answer you but you didn't vote any answer...

Comment: @Ophir Gvirtzer I was examining those methods suggested. What i wanted to get from this question was to find out whether there is easier way to implement object tracking than using some other methods like optical flow or other gaussian mixture model. Guess i have no choice but to find out open sources... Anyway thanks for answering and clarifying the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scheme is quite adequate to cases where the camera is fix and the background is stationary. Indoor and man-controlled scenes are more appropriate to this approach than outdoor and natural scenes .I've contributed to a detection system that worked basically on the same principals you suggested. But of course the details are crucial. A few remarks based on my experience

1. Your initialization step can cause very slow convergence to a normal state. You set the background to the first frames, and then pieces of background coming behind moving objects will be considered as objects. A better approach is to take the median of N first frames.
2. Simple subtraction may not be enough in cases of changing light condition etc. You may find a similarity criterion better for your application.
3. simple thresholding on the difference image may not be enough. A simple approach is to dilate the foreground for the sake of not updating the background on pixels that where accidentally identified as such.
4. Your step 4 is unclear, I assumed that you mean that you update the foreground only on those places that are identified as background on the last frame. Note that with such a simple approach, pixels that are actually background may be stuck forever with a "foreground" labeling, as you don't update the background under them. There are many possible solutions to this.

Comment: Oh i just deleted step4 which overlaps with step1. I just meant to update background image periodically.

Comment: I consider this a bad idea. If you set the image periodically to the current frame, you get the problem I talked about in (1) after every update. You have basically two options: 1. update only the pixels on the background, i.e. not detected as objects. Her you need to handle issue (4) in some way 2. Update the background independently from the object tracking , by consider long statistics of every pixels. This might be more computationally demanding.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider illumination change(gradually or suddenly) in scene, you will see that your method does not work.

There are more robust solutions for these problems. One of these(maybe the best) is **Gaussian Mixture Model** applied for background subtraction.

You can use [BackgroundSubtractorMOG2](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#backgroundsubtractormog2) (implementation of GMM) in OpenCV library.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this problem, and it will really depend on the input images as to which method will be the most appropriate. It may be worth doing some reading on the [topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow)

The method you are suggesting may work, but it's a slightly non-standard approach to this problem. My main concern would be that subtracting several images from the background could lead to saturation and then you may lose some detail of the motion. It may be better to take difference between consecutive images, and then apply the binarization / thresholding to these images.

Another (more complex) approach which has worked for me in the past is to take subregions of the image and then cross-correlate with the new image. The peak in this correlation can be used to identify the direction of movement - it's a useful approach if more then one thing is moving.

It may also be possible to use a combination of the two approaches above for example.

1. Subtract second image from the first background.
2. Threshold etc to find the ROI where movement is occurring
3. Use a pattern matching approach to track subsequent movement focussed on the ROI detected above.

The best approach will depend on you application but there are lots of papers on this topic